# React fetch data of multiple components on event

Tags: jquery, reactjs

Currently having multiple lists on a page. The first contains data about admins, the second list contains data about standard users. The problem is I have a separate button on the page that will create a new record of either admin or user or even more bizzare thing such as a new product. What I need is an ability to refresh(fetch new data of) all the lists on the page. Right now there is only one component GenericList and its fields are generated automatically. That means I can instantiate the same component for product, users and admins. But what I need now is an ability to refresh all the datagrids(lists) when a new item is created.

I tried using .bind() and tried calling .trigger() but for some reason this doesn't work at all.

Basically I just want to call method fetchNewData for all the GenericLists that are rendered on the page where a record is created.

Ideally, the best way how to do it would be

```
$('.generic-lists').each(function(){
$(this).trigger('fetchNewData'); }
```

just iterating thru all lists that are on the page and calling the method that I binded to them in ComponentDidMount function.

Comment: How is that question related to the Ruby\RubyOnRails? Also it is unclear for me what you want, code, advise or whatever.

Comment: Please read the help section on how to ask questions